# Spring Data JPA find by embedded object property

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to write a Spring Data JPA repository interface method signature that will let me find entities with a property of an embedded object in that entity. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how?

Here's my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK_UPDATE_QUEUE", indexes = { uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "bookId", "region" }, name = "UK01_BOOK_UPDATE_QUEUE"))
public class QueuedBook implements Serializable {

    @Embedded
    @NotNull
    private BookId bookId;

    ...

}

@Embeddable
public class BookId implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=40)
    private String bookId;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Region region;

    ...

}

public interface QueuedBookRepo extends JpaRepository<QueuedBook, Long> {

    //I'd like to write a method like this, but can't figure out how to search by region,
    //when region is actually a part of the embedded BookId
    Page<QueuedBook> findByRegion(Region region, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Can I write a query for this using Spring Data?

Comment: Doesn't `findByBookIdRegion(Region region, Pageable pageable)` do the trick?

Comment: Yep, that does it. I couldn't find documentation for that anywhere. Is it hidden or implied somewhere I didn't see?

Comment: Turned that into an answer and added a link to the relevant section of the reference docs.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

This method name should do the trick:

```
Page<QueuedBook> findByBookIdRegion(Region region, Pageable pageable);
```

More info on that in the section about [query derivation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) of the reference docs.

Comment: What if I have a list of Embeddable? or element  collection?

Comment: If we want findBy query with 3 preperty then what will be syntax?
is it like findByPro1AndPro2AndPro3?

Comment: Does such a query always result in an inner join?

I am doing `One findByIdAndTwoId(Long oneId, Long twoId);` and results in a query of the form: `select ...... from one one_ left outer join two two_ on one_.two_id = two_.id where one_id = ? and two_.id = ?`

Comment: @surendrapanday: Yes, `findByCol1AndCol2` works when you have multiple columns

Answer (score 49):

The above - findByBookIdRegion() did not work for me. The following works with the latest release of String Data JPA:

```
Page<QueuedBook> findByBookId_Region(Region region, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Your cases might be related to ambiguity as discussed at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Answer (score 9):

If you are using BookId as an combined primary key, then remember to change your interface from:

```
public interface QueuedBookRepo extends JpaRepository<QueuedBook, Long> {
```

to:

```
public interface QueuedBookRepo extends JpaRepository<QueuedBook, BookId> {
```

And change the annotation @Embedded to @EmbeddedId, in your QueuedBook class like this:

```
public class QueuedBook implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
@NotNull
private BookId bookId;

...
```

Answer (score 1):

According to me, Spring doesn't handle all the cases with ease. In your case
the following should do the trick

```
Page<QueuedBook> findByBookIdRegion(Region region, Pageable pageable);
```

or

```
Page<QueuedBook> findByBookId_Region(Region region, Pageable pageable);
```

However, it also depends on the naming convention of fields that you have in your `@Embeddable` class,

e.g. the following field might not work in any of the styles that mentioned above

```
private String cRcdDel;
```

I tried with both the cases (as follows) and it didn't work (it seems like Spring doesn't handle this type of naming conventions(i.e. to many Caps , especially in the beginning - 2nd letter (not sure about if this is the only case though)

```
Page<QueuedBook> findByBookIdCRcdDel(String cRcdDel, Pageable pageable);
```

or

```
Page<QueuedBook> findByBookIdCRcdDel(String cRcdDel, Pageable pageable);
```

When I renamed column to

```
private String rcdDel;
```

my following solutions work fine without any issue:

```
Page<QueuedBook> findByBookIdRcdDel(String rcdDel, Pageable pageable);
```

OR

```
Page<QueuedBook> findByBookIdRcdDel(String rcdDel, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: For both or's the statements are the same!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing this.

1. Using [derived methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries.declaring-interfaces).
2. Using [native queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters).
3. Use the [specification interface](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) to construct complex queries.

Below are code snippet showing how you can query data using embedded properties.

The repository extends the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface.

```
public interface QuedBookRepository extends JpaRepository<QueuedBook, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<QueuedBook>{
    //Using derived query methods
    Page<QueuedBook> findByBookId_Region(Region region, Pageable pageable);


    //Using native queries
    @Query("SELECT qb FROM QueuedBook qb "
        +"WHERE qb.bookId.region = :region")
    Page<QueuedBook> findByBookIdRegion(Region region, Pageable pageable);
    
    
    //Using specification interface
    static Specification<QueuedBook> findByBookIdRegion(Region region){
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equals(root.get("bookId").get("region"), region);
    }
}
```

To use the repository methods, access them as follows.

```
//In your service methods

Region region = ....;
Pageable pageable = ....;


//Using derived query methods
Page<QueuedBook> booksPage = repository.findByBookId_Region(region, pageable);

//Using native queries
Page<QueuedBook> booksPage = repository.findByBookIdRegion(region, pageable);

//Using specification interface
Specification<QueuedBook> spec = QuedBookRepository.findByBookIdRegion(region);
Page<QueuedBook> booksPage = repository.findAll(spec, pageable);
```