# Spring Data JPA: find nested object

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a LOCATION entity and it contains COUNTRY, STATE and CITY. And I have a LocationRepository interface defined as:

```
public interface SpringDataLocationRepository extends LocationRepository,
        Repository<Location, Integer> {
}
```

I want to find all the state by country. I can follow the method name standard to query everything for LOCATION entity. If I want List, do I need to create StateRepository interface and query everything about STATE in there? If I can just get it from LocationRepository, what's the method looks like? I assume it will look something like below (of course it doesn't work).

List findStateByCountryCountryId(Integer id) throws DataAccessException;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below method should work:

```
List<Location> findByCountryId(Integer id)
```

Then you can get state from the `Location` objects in the list.

PS: Of course, this is not tested/executed by me.

Comment: this related question/answer more thoroughly explains this situation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441411/spring-data-jpa-find-by-embedded-object-property