# How to search with JpaRepository and nested list of objects?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

**Description**

There is a `PersonRepository` and `Person` entity,
`Person` class contains `List<Qualification>`. `Qualification` class has 3 simple fields.

I have tried to add `@Query` annotation on custom method and use JPQL to get the results, but `Qualification` class fields were not available for manipulation in JPQL as it repository itself contains `List<Qualification>` instead of just a simple field of `Qualification`.

How can I search by these Qualification's nested fields?

**Query**

Now I need to find list of person entity where qualification's experienceInMonths is greater than 3 and less than 9 AND qualification's name field = 'java'.

**Code**

Person.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 2)
private String name;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 2)
private String surname;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = java.util.ArrayList.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Qualification> qualifications = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

PersonRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

Qualification.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Qualification implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String experienceInMonths;
}
```

**EDIT:** not duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441411/spring-data-jpa-find-by-embedded-object-property?noredirect=1&lq=1), as here is the collection of nested objects. Not just single reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data JPA find by embedded object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441411/spring-data-jpa-find-by-embedded-object-property)

Comment: as mentioned in edit of post, this question does not corresopont to proposed answer. as you can see in the code pasted, there is an issue with `List` of an objects - not just one of it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, change `experienceInMonths` from `String` to `int` (otherwise you can not compare the string with the number). Then you can try to use this 'sausage':

```
List<Person> findByQualifications_experienceInMonthsGreaterThanAndQualifications_experienceInMonthsLessThanAndName(int experienceGreater, int experienceLess, String name);
```

Or you can try to use this pretty nice method:

```
@Query("select p from Person p left join p.qualifications q where q.experienceInMonths > ?1 and q.experienceInMonths < ?2 and q.name = ?3")
List<Person> findByQualification(int experienceGreater, int experienceLess, String name);
```

Comment: did it worked for you locally? the JPQL version gaves me `org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: ` and the sausage one: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null] of basic type`. Even with changing Qualification#experienceInMonths type to `int`

Comment: @DevDio Try to add `@Entity` to `Qualification` and replace `@ElementCollection` to `@OneToMany` (a similar variant works for me...)

Comment: Ok, finally got it working, but it required implementation of separate `Qualification` table in Hibernate. which holds FK to Person (@Entity, additional field person with @ManyToOne) + `QualificationRepository` was mandatory.

Also tested proposed methods, the version with JPQL worked fine, yet the 'sausage' name required to be adjusted to:
`findByQualifications_experienceInMonthsGreaterThanAndQualifications_experienceInMonthsLessThanAndQualifications_Name`. 
Otherwise it searched for Person name. Big thanks for help @Cepr0!

Comment: @DevDio 'QualificationRepository was mandatory' - it will be not necessary if you use [@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many). Then you can use only one Person repo to store both entities.

Answer (score 1):

W can use ‘_’ (Underscore) character inside the method name to define where JPA should try to split.

In this case our method name will be

```
List<Person> findByQualification_name(String name);
```

Comment: This doesnt work here, can you please check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69753527/redis-jpa-repository-can-not-find-by-nested-object-id