# Selecting where an entity contains a list which elements have another list

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am writing a JPQL query in spring JPA and i have the following scenario. I have a  entity Margin which contains a list of PerPeriodMargin and each element of PerPeriodMargin contains a list of MarginFactor.
code:

```
@Entity
public class Margin {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "margin", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<PerPeriodMargin> perPeriodMargins;
}


@Entity
public class PerPeriodMargin{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  private Margin margin;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "perPeriodMargin", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<MarginFactor> marginFactors;
}

@Entity
public class MarginFactor{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  private Underlying underlying;
  @ManyToOne
  private PerPeriodMargin perPeriodMargin;
}
```

I would like to select all Margin where MarginFactor underlying.id is passed as a parameter in a single jpql query?
Any suggestions?

i activated hibernate logging by this line in application.properties "logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG" and i have been confused about the generated SQL queries. its seems there is something wrong about that multiple join. can any one explain this.

select * from margin m inner join per_period_margin ppm on m.id = ppm.margin_id join margin_factor mf on ppm.id = mf.per_period_margin_id where mf.underlying_id = ? and m.id = (select margin_id from trading_account ta where ta.id = ?)

and on for perPeriodMargin

select perperiodm0_.margin_id as margin_i5_12_0_, perperiodm0_.id as id1_12_0_, perperiodm0_.id as id1_12_1_, perperiodm0_.end_time as end_time2_12_1_, perperiodm0_.margin_id as margin_i5_12_1_, perperiodm0_.name as name3_12_1_, perperiodm0_.start_time as start_ti4_12_1_ from per_period_margin perperiodm0_ **where perperiodm0_.margin_id=?**

until now all is seams good.

finally ther are two other queries that try to get marginFactors.

select marginfact0_.per_period_margin_id as per_peri6_9_0_, marginfact0_.id as id1_9_0_, marginfact0_.id as id1_9_1_, marginfact0_.bid as bid2_9_1_, marginfact0_.notional as notional3_9_1_, marginfact0_.offer as offer4_9_1_, marginfact0_.per_period_margin_id as per_peri6_9_1_, marginfact0_.settlement as settleme5_9_1_, marginfact0_.underlying_id as underlyi7_9_1_, underlying1_.id as id1_24_2_, underlying1_.digits as digits2_24_2_, underlying1_.display as display3_24_2_, underlying1_.enable as enable4_24_2_, underlying1_.enable_buy as enable_b5_24_2_, underlying1_.enable_sell as enable_s6_24_2_, underlying1_.focus_digits as focus_di7_24_2_, underlying1_.focus_position as focus_po8_24_2_, underlying1_.left_currency_id as left_cu11_24_2_, underlying1_.name as name9_24_2_, underlying1_.right_currency_id as right_c12_24_2_, underlying1_.temporary_disable as tempora10_24_2_, currency2_.id as id1_3_3_, currency2_.digits as digits2_3_3_, currency2_.enable_buy as enable_b3_3_3_, currency2_.enable_sell as enable_s4_3_3_, currency2_.name as name5_3_3_, currency2_.symbol as symbol6_3_3_, currency2_.temporary_disable as temporar7_3_3_, currency3_.id as id1_3_4_, currency3_.digits as digits2_3_4_, currency3_.enable_buy as enable_b3_3_4_, currency3_.enable_sell as enable_s4_3_4_, currency3_.name as name5_3_4_, currency3_.symbol as symbol6_3_4_, currency3_.temporary_disable as temporar7_3_4_ from margin_factor marginfact0_ left outer join underlying underlying1_ on marginfact0_.underlying_id=underlying1_.id left outer join currency currency2_ on underlying1_.left_currency_id=currency2_.id left outer join currency currency3_ on underlying1_.right_currency_id=currency3_.id **where marginfact0_.per_period_margin_id=?**

and as we see here in the last query there are only one where condition on perPeriodmarginId. as I think it must also contain underlying condition, because this query is the responsible of fetching marginFactors where we must extract the data that who have a specific underlyingId.

I'm really serious about this question please can someone explain that or is it a bug in hibernate!

Comment: what have you tried so far? Add your code to the question please

Comment: please check my new update of this question.

Comment: Use native query, ORM is not for this kind of complex relationship query.

You need be very careful about the SQL generated by JPQL.

Comment: i found this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996810/how-to-search-with-jparepository-and-nested-list-of-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1], it is not verry similar with my case but i'm asking if we can do something like that
right here

Comment: Is this?: `select m FROM Margin m
    JOIN m.perPeriodMargins ppm
    JOIN ppm.marginFactors mf
    JOIN mf.underlying und
    WHERE und.id = :idUnderlying`

Comment: sorry no it's not correct. i have a freak NullPointerException.

Comment: i created this nativeQuery:
select * from margin m inner join per_period_margin ppm on m.id = ppm.margin_id join margin_factor mf on ppm.id = mf.per_period_margin_id where mf.underlying_id = 2 and m.id = (select margin_id from trading_account ta where ta.id = 1).
the problem is when i excute this on mysql it gives the right solution but in spring data using @Query(value="", nativeQuery= true) it return a false result.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query:

```
select m 
FROM Margin m 
JOIN m.perPeriodMargins ppm 
JOIN ppm.marginFactors mf 
JOIN mf.underlying und 
WHERE und.id = :id
```

Comment: It returns a false result.
for example i put und.id = 2 and it return all the margin factors (und.id = 2 and 3).
can you explain that please.

Comment: Maybe multiple Margins have that Underlying with that id. Check the SQL query and the data to be sure.

Comment: to be more clear i'm added to this query a condition on margin id "where m.id = :marginId". and it also give a false result