# Want to find users by type

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, filter

This is my model I want to find users in the BusinessInformation object by partnerAssigned but am confused how to do it .Able to do it with name or anything else not a list or object

```
    public class Entity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Address address;
    private BusinessInformation businessInformation;
    private Binary image;
    private List<UserRolls> userRolls;

//Constructor 

//Getters and Setters

//BusinessInformation  Model
private String businessName;
    private String businessType;
    private String businessSize;
    private String telephoneNumber;
    private String registrationNumber;
    private String productAssigned;
    private String partnerAssigned;
    private String salesmenEmail;
//Constructor 

//Getters and Setters
    List<User> findUsersByPartnerAssigned(String partnerAssigned);
```

In my repository I am tryng something like this

```
@Query("{ 'partnerAssigned' : ?0 }")
    List<User> findUsersByPartnerAssigned(String partnerAssigned);
```

And my Controller

```
//Get all Entities by type
@RequestMapping(value = "/{partner}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<User> getAllByPartner(@PathVariable("partner") String partner) {
    List<User> user = this.entityRepository.findUsersByPartnerAssigned(partner);
    return user;
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested properties traversal as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) in the docs. The example given is `Person -> Address -> ZipCode` which is similar structure to your problem. Also you can use direct query ( using joins since `BusinessInformation` is referenced in `Entity`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996810/how-to-search-with-jparepository-and-nested-list-of-objects) for an example.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding , how would the controller look for something like this

Comment: Trying to use a path variable way but ,doesnt seem to be working      @RequestMapping(value = "/{partner}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Entity> getAllByPartner(@PathVariable("partner") String partner) {
        List<Entity> user = this.entityRepository.findByBusinessInformation_PartnerAssigned(partner);
        return user;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `List<Entity> findByBusinessInformation_partnerAssigned(String name);`

Hope you have annotated

```
@Document
public class Entity{
}
```

And Repository

```
public EntityRepository extends MongoRepository<Entity,String>{}
```