# Redis Jpa repository can not find by nested object id

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Here is my redis entity

```
@RedisHash("imei")
public class NeirResponse {

    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String id;

    private List<ImeiResponse> imeiList;
}
```

And here is `ImeiResponse`

```
@Data
public class ImeiResponse {

    private String imei;

    private String type;
}
```

In my repository i am trying to find by nested `imei`. Here is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface NeirRepository extends JpaRepository<NeirResponse, String> {

    Optional<NeirResponse> findByImeiListImei(String imei);
}
```

But it is returning null, although data exists.

So far i have tried the following

1. findByImeiList_Imei
2. findInImeiListByImei
3. findByImeiListImei
4. findByImeiList_imei

How do i write proper method name?

***N.B I have tried several SO questions, but could not solve, so please dont mark as duplicate.***