# Crud Repository how to use `findBy` with data member's data member

Tags: spring, spring-boot, repository, crud, spring-repositories

I have a structure of something like this -

```
@Entity
@Table("transaction")
public class TransactionBean{

    @Id
    Long txnId;

    //other stuff
}
@Entity
@Table("someclass")
public class SomeClass{

    @Id
    TransactionBean transactionBean;

    //other stuff
}
```

And the repositories for each -

```
public interface TransactionRepo extends CrudRepository<TransactionBean, Long){
    //some stuff
}

public interface SomeClassRepo extends CrudRepository<SomeClass, TransactionBean){
    //some stuff
}
```

Now i need to find a record in `SomeClass` using `txnId`. Is there any one line function like shown below or do i need to first get a `TransactionBean` and then use it to search `SomeClass`.

```
TransactionBean txnBean;
//some stuff done with it

SomeClassRepo someClassRepo;
//I need some function like this
SomeClass someClass = someCLassRepo.findBySOMETHING(txnBean.getTxnId());
```

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441411/spring-data-jpa-find-by-embedded-object-property

Comment: thanks that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand you do this (I am currently wonrking on something like this) is:

1) Define a new interface with the method.

```
public interface CustomSomeClassRepo{
    public SomeClass findByTxnId(Long id);
}
```

2) Have the repo interface also extend this interface:

```
public interface SomeClassRepo extends CrudRepository<SomeClass, TransactionBean),
                                       CustomSomeClassRepo{
        //some stuff
}
```

*Note: I am using JpaRepository instead of CRUDRepository.*

3) Write an implementation class for the method in the CustomSomeClassRepo interface. **It has to be named as the interface plus appending "Impl"**

```
public class CustomSomeClassRepoImpl implements CustomSomeClassRepo{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public SomeClass findByTxnId(Long id){

        /* Here you run the Query you need using the EntityManager and the id.
           and return an instance of SomeClass;
         */

    }
}
```

`@PersistenceContext` will inject the `EntityManager` instance.

4) Finally you can call `findByTxnId(Long id)` from the instance of `SomeClassRepo`.

Comment: i have already implemented the solution provided by max and it is easier to do, check this to link for mare details about it https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Comment: Yes, I agree, I think this way of doing it is to implement custom queries that don't fit the look up by attributes.