# JPA by Object in the Object using an atribute that is not @Id

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I would like to know if it is possible to create a JPA without using the @Query annotation to get the results from an atribute of the object inside the object I am querying.

I am able to to `List findAllById(Long id) just fine, but what I would like to know is if it's possible to make a similar query that will look for the atribute of an object inside that class, example of my domain as follows:

```
public class OcorrenciaParticipante
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cod_ocorrencia_participante")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cod_ocorrencia", referencedColumnName = "cod_ocorrencia")
    private Ocorrencia ocorrencia;

public class Ocorrencia 
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cod_ocorrencia")
    private Long codigo;
```

What I want is to write something like `List<OcorrenciaParticipante> findAllByOcorrencia` to get a list of OcorrenciaParticipante using the `codigo` atribute from the Ocorrencia class.

When I do the above, and call my endpoint passing the value of variable codigo, I get the exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [project.model.oc.Ocorrencia (n/a)]`

I have tried some things using the information from here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to include the nested property inside the repository method signature:

```
List<OcorrenciaParticipante> findAllByOcorrenciaCodigo
```

Spring docs on it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Similar question with more discussion: [Spring Data JPA find by embedded object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441411/spring-data-jpa-find-by-embedded-object-property)

Comment: Indeed... I was sure I tried that and it failed, likely I made a typo. Thanks