# Spring data jpa find by multiple fields in embedded key

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I need to find an object using two fields of an embedded key

Here is the embedded key:

```
public class OrderItemId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1163347452811191867L;

    @Column(name = "order_code", length = 25)
    private String orderCode;

    @Column(name = "barcode", length = 25)
    private String barcode;

    // ....
}
```

Here is the class of the object I want to query:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_item")
public class OrderItem {

    @EmbeddedId
    @NotNull
    private OrderItemId id;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    // ...
}
```

As in this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441411/spring-data-jpa-find-by-embedded-object-property/24457687)

To query by embedded key `orderCode`, I can write something like this

```
public List<OrderItem> findById_OrderCode(String orderCode);
```

and it works!

But I don't know how to query by both `orderCode` and `barcode`. I have tried some forms of `and` but no use.

Comment: Please put your answer in a proper answer instead of putting it in the question. This will let others see that the question is answered.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update as your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind, I have figured out the query, it is

```
public OrderItem findById_OrderCodeAndId_Barcode(String orderCode, String barcode);
```